# NSNumberFormatter.string(from: ) maximum possible Value exceeded does not result in Overflow - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, overflow, nsnumberformatter

I am converting numbers to pure English words, and I ran into some very odd situations: `NSNumberFormatter` has a strange output, smaller than the desired result, but the number taken as parameter doesn't cause an overflow.

I have the following code:

```
 import Foundation
 var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
 numberFormatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
 var result: String?
 result = numberFormatter.string(from: 999999999999999999)
 print(result ?? "nil")
```

and this prints `eighteen quadrillion fourteen trillion three hundred ninety-eight billion five hundred nine million four hundred eighty-one thousand nine hundred eighty-four`, which is the equivalent of `18014398509481984`< `999999999999999999`. If I try to get the words from `18014398509481984`, the result is the one I expected, the string described above. However, if I add one more `9` to  `999..`, it crashes with the message:

> integer literal `9999999999999999999` overflows when stored into `Int`

Here is a [Swift Sandbox Test](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58964cf63f66821add33417c), in order to make the question more *understandable*.

---

**My actual question is:** Assuming that the output of the first try: `180140398509481984` is some kind of limit for `numberFormatter.string(from:)`, why does `999999999999999999` not result in Overflow, but just displays that limit, and `9999999999999999999` (with an extra 9) results in Overflow?

Comment: Strange. Even if you use `180140398509481985`, you still get `180140398509481984` when spelled out.

Comment: It's a strange limit too. It's between 2^57 and 2^58.

Comment: @rmaddy this is exactly what I am asking. Is it some kind of limit to that function only, or is it a problem with Int / NSNumber max value?

Comment: For some reason, I could not find any special property of that number, I don't know what is going on

Comment: It appears to be some kind of limit/bug to the `spellOut` style of `NumberFormatter`.

Comment: Yes, it may be a bug related to the **spellOut** or **string(from:)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134875/discussion-between-xcoder123-and-rmaddy).

Comment: I just ran a macOS/Objective-C version of the same code and got the same strange result. So it's not specific to iOS or Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy - "Even if you use 180140398509481985, you still get 180140398509481984 ... It's a strange limit, too. It's between 2^57 and 2^58" ... The OP didn't transcribe the number correctly. It's `18_014_398_509_481_984`, i.e. `2^54`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `9_999_999_999_999_999_999` causes an `Int` overflow because it is larger than `Int64.max` is `9_223_372_036_854_775_807` (i.e. `0x7fffffffffffffff`).

Regarding why number formatter is capping out at `18_014_398_509_481_984` (i.e., 2<sup>54</sup>, `0x40000000000000`) for `.spelledOut`, that seems suspiciously like a bug stemming from 64-bit floating point representions of the value. We can't be sure without going through the source for `NSNumberFormatter` and `NSNumber` in some detail, but I suggest this because the upper ceiling here is, coincidentally, precisely double the largest integer value that a 64-bit floating point type can capture faithfully.

Comment: Foundation and Core Foundation are open sourced. The [`CFNumberFormatterCreateStringWithNumber`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/173e9ea16cf1a0ed9b21cc11ea8a2d15b3f8dca9/CoreFoundation/Locale.subproj/CFNumberFormatter.c) function even have an omnimous warning that "The values of CFNumbers with large unsigned 64-bit ints don't survive well through this". Look like Apple already knew about this problem.